# Reshape a 1D array into a 2D array in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

How can I "reshape" a one-dimensional array into a two-dimensional array in Google Apps Script?

In Python, it can be done in [Numpy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy). Is there a way to do it without using a `for` loop?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: numPy just abstracts away the process of iterating over an array; under the hood I'm sure there is some form of looping going on. If you're just looking for the convenience of a familiar interface, there are javascript ports of numPy that you try integrating into your GAS project. Just look for a port with little or no dependencies on npm.

Answer (score 0):

That should be easy enough to do with plain JavaScript. Try the following:

```
function testReshapeArray() {
  const array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  const reshaped = reshapeArray_(array, 3);
  console.log('old array ' + JSON.stringify(array));
  console.log('new array ' + JSON.stringify(reshaped));
}

function reshapeArray_(array, numColumns) {
  const result = [];
  let row = [];
  let column = 0;
  array.flat().forEach(value => {
    if (column < numColumns) {
      row.push(value);
      column += 1;
    } else {
      result.push(row);
      row = [value];
      column = 1;
    }
  });
  row.length = numColumns;
  result.push(row);
  return result;
}
```

The `row.length = numColumns` bit will fill the last row in the result with `undefined` values when there are leftover values in the array. Remove that line if you want to keep the total number of values in the array unchanged.

`testReshapeArray()` will log:

```
old array [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
new array [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[9,null,null]]
```

I am certain that there are more efficient ways of doing this with a `map-reduce` pattern or similar, but since the performance of Apps Script is dominated by read-write operations rather than array manipulation, that should not make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the convenience of using numPy and its familiar interface in your GAS projects. This is achievable by using [numjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/numjs), one of the more popular javascript ports of numPy available on npm (Node Package Manager).

Just create an empty script in your GAS project and copy/paste the [minified source for the numjs library](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numjs/0.16.0/numjs.min.js) into it.

Then you can reference the library via the **`nj`** object and do stuff like this:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

let result = nj.array(arr).reshape([3, 4]);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numjs/0.16.0/numjs.min.js"></script>
```

---

**NOTE**: To use the numjs library you need to have the V8 runtime enabled in your GAS editor (this is now the default in the new IDE but if you're still using the old editor, you can switch to V8 by setting the appropriate property in you project manifest file).